# Can I create dash callbacks for a list of unknown number of buttons. I.e don't know how many buttons the list will have and how many callbacks needed

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash, dashboard

My dash project includes functionality that the user can customise alerts. These alerts appear in a customised alerts list with a delete button that gives the user the ability to delete a customised alert from the list.

[scheenshot of dashboard feature]

[image: 1]

This list is created with the following code:

```
    @callback(
        Output('customized-list','children'),
        Input('customized-alerts-button','n_clicks'),
        State('customized_alerts','data'),prevent_initial_call=True)
    def showCustomizedAlerts(_,customized_alerts):
        return [html.H2('Customized alerts', style={"textAlign": "left"}),
                html.Ul([html.Li(html.Div([
                    html.Div([i],style={'display':'inline-block'}),
                    html.Div([html.Button('Delete alert',id='delete-alert-button'+str(customized_alerts.index(i)))],style={'display':'inline-block'})])) for i in customized_alerts])]
```

Now in order for the delete alert feature to work I need callbacks for every delete button (with id's 'delete-alert-button1','delete-alert-button2',...,'delete-alert-buttonm' for m alerts). Is there a way I can implement this such that this works for however many alerts a user wants to make? My intuition says that maybe I can create callbacks in a loop, in the same way as the button are made. Something like:

```
@callback(..Input('delete-alert-button'+str(customized_alerts.index(i)),'n_clicks')... for i in customised_alerts
```

As a quick fix I just created a bunch of callbacks so it covers so many alerts. However, if the user creates more alerts than I accounted for this becomes a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks

You can use pattern matching on the callback definitions, that will pick up any elements that are identified by an ID.